# Javascript + dynamic menu + current link style (CSS) + PHP based site

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, dynamic

**Here's my setup:**

I have a modular site which uses dynamic inclusion. The header is required by the main page. The main page is only in charge of rendering content from specific links on the site. Therefore, external links to CSS and js files are found in the head of the main page, and the content pages are (php) document fragments designed to be included as content within the main page.

On the client side, I would like for my menu to function dynamically using Javascript. I already use CSS to style the `:hover`, `:active`, and `:visited` pseudoclasses. I defined two separate classes relating to both active and inactive buttons. I wrote the js, set up onclick events for the links, and externally linked the script.

**The problem**

Firebug is detecting the script, but when I click the links the function does not fire.

**Code**

HTML menu element with inline function call:

```
 <ul>
        <li class="navLnk"><a href="mylinks.php" tabindex="2" accesskey="2" onclick"asgnActv(this)">BANDS</a></li>
        <li class="navLnk"><a href="mylinks.php" tabindex="3" accesskey="3" onclick"asgnActv(this)">RELEASES</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Javascript function:

```
function asgnActv(e){
if (e.className == 'navLnk') {
    $lnkArr = document.getElementsByClassName('actvLnk');
    for (i=0; i<$linkArr.length; i++) {
        $linkArr[i].className = 'navLnk';
    }
    e.className = 'actvLnk';
  }
}
```

External js link in head of main php page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're missing an `=` sign: `onclick=`

Comment: Don't use intrusive `onclick` attribute element, do it all in the script [jQuery will save you a lot of time in this].

Comment: If that is all I missed!...Oh sheesh...

Comment: @moonwave99 can you offer me an example?

Comment: Added the = signs. Now it steps into the function but does not identify the class attribute to continue.

Comment: Ah and first of all - if you click a link you will go to `mylinks.php` and the page will be reloaded, so you script will have no use. If you want the current section to have a different class, do it server side.

Comment: My links actually only reload the content section. They call $_GET to check which file to require. I think I am on the way to getting it working, but this is definitely where my concern was focused. I didn't know if I was making a silly mistake or if my PHP and js intentions were conflicting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is two mistakes one missing "=" sign mentioned by @Joseph and also in the js code you are checking its className whereas this class "navLnk" is defined to its parent element i.e. `< li >`

So to get worked this either specify the class to anchor element or use below script if you want it for li elements

```
function asgnActv(e){
   if (e.parentNode.className == 'navLnk') {
     $lnkArr = document.getElementsByClassName('actvLnk');
     for (i=0; i<$linkArr.length; i++) {
       $linkArr[i].className = 'navLnk';
     }
     e.parentNode.className = 'actvLnk';
   }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This is perfect. The only other thing that I did not do was anticipate if none of them are active. I will have to make a check for that, too! Thanks! I am glad it was so simple.